# VBA: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed when copying from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first VBA script, so I may be missing something really basic. However, I've googled this issue and none of the solutions presented seem to fit my situation. All that I am trying to do is copy a column of data from one workbook, and paste only the values, while transposing, to another workbook. When I run the Macro, I get the error "Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetEverything()

Dim fPATH As String, fNAME As String
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim DestBook As Workbook
Dim number As Double

fPATH = "\\NetworkShare\Path\to\file\"
Set DestBook = ThisWorkbook

For i = 1 To 31
    fNAME = "TimeStep " & i & ".xlsx"
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(fPATH & fNAME)

    CurrentBook.Sheets("FFT Normal Force").Range("E2:E257").Copy

    number = i + 2

    DestBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & CStr(number)).PasteSpecial Paste:=x1PasteValues, Operation:=x1None, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    CurrentBook.Close False
Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm interested in learning, too, so I'd love to know not only what is wrong, but why.

The error occurs on the line 
    DestBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & CStr(number)).PasteSpecial Paste:=x1PasteValues, Operation:=x1None, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Comment: LOL - Simple mistake that took me a while to catch onto... In your code, you have `x1PasteValues` and `x1None` ... The value after `x` should be an "L" not a "1" ... `xlPasteValues`, `xlNone`

Comment: WOW. Can't believe I missed that one. It's still giving me the same error though, even after I fixed that mistake.

Comment: If you are still having issues after correcting that, you might try adding `DestBook.Activate` before the PasteSpecial code runs.  I've had that resolve similar issues.

Comment: I added `DestBook.Activate` on the line before the error occurs, and it didn't fix anything. I'm still getting the same error on the same line.

Comment: I just tried it on my machine and it worked.... If you changed the "1" to an "l" for those 2 and have a sheet **exactly named** "Sheet2" in your current workbook, this should work.... You shouldn't have to activate the workbook first either....

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a "Sheet2" in your destination workbook?

Comment: Perhaps `DestBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate`?  Seems perhaps trivial but I know this has resolved method failures for me before.  Make sure you indeed have a worksheet named exactly "Sheet2" in your DestBook.  If the names of your worksheet will be changing, I think you should look into referring to sheets by their [code name](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm).  I also agree you shouldn't _have_ to activate your workbook first, but it inexplicably works for me.

Comment: Joshua, that did the trick! Thanks for your help! I added `DestBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate` right before the offending line. I definitely do have a sheet named Sheet2 in the destination workbook, but I'll look into using the code name when I clean up the macro.

Comment: Code names are an excellent route in the event the name of the worksheet is changed.  Code names are constant (unless explicitly changed, but that's another issue).

Comment: It is not necessary to activate the destination workbook or worksheet to PasteSpecial. I just ran your code without error in 2010. You should definitely add Option Explicit to the top of your modules.